Query writing out the same record for entire recordset
I have a select query in SQL Server which works fine.
When I convert it to an insert query, it stores the correct number of rows, but they are all duplicates of the first row.
Even when I write out row by row using a recordset, it shows correctly in debug but the records are all identical in the output table.
Simple test with results:
sql = "SELECT TOP 50 Person_ID, category_Code, Area_Code, Subject_Code, Institute_ID " & _
      "FROM ( " & _
      "    SELECT DISTINCT Person_ID, category_Code, Area_Code, Subject_Code, Institute_ID " & _
      "    FROM Person_Subject_view " & _
      "    WHERE category_Code = '4LE' " & _
      ") AS DistinctRecords " & _
      "ORDER BY NEWID()"


' Execute the query and get the recordset
Set rs = conn.Execute(sql)

' Loop through the recordset and insert each record into Order_Output
Do While Not rs.EOF
    insertsql = "INSERT INTO dbo_Order_Output (Order_Num, Person_ID, category_Code, Area_Code, Subject_Code, Institute_ID) " & _
                "VALUES (" & TempVars!PassOrder & ", '" & rs!Person_Id & "', '" & rs!category_code & "', '" & rs!Area_Code & "', '" & rs!Subject_Code & "', '" & rs!Institute_id & "')"
    Debug.Print rs!Person_Id & " " & rs!Subject_Code
    Forms!frm_Order_Extract_Progress!StatusMsg = "Writing Record..." & rs.RecordCount
    Forms!frm_Order_Extract_Progress.Repaint

    DoCmd.RunSQL insertsql <-(tried command aswell)
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

This is the debug print:
6999966 8582
6564203 6F13
7434324 58D0
5340162 2211
5395077 5880
6750094 8AK3
5564490 5140
7792156 8270
7182004 57A0
7395781 5754
7701971 32A0
6689606 5B00
7668123 1344
5960161 1643
7556080 8910

Here is the input in the file:
6999966 8582
6999966 8582
6999966 8582
6999966 8582
6999966 8582
6999966 8582
6999966 8582
6999966 8582
6999966 8582
6999966 8582
6999966 8582
6999966 8582

I tried several alternatives including using params.

This doesn't look like a Azure SQL Database but a problem with the code you provided in an untagged/specified language.

That code, however, does looks highly dangerous as it's open to injection.

You didn't provide enough information. According to the debug output, the logic seems OK and the program is reading all records. Then, the problem is in the INSERT. What is DoCmd? Try again using Command(). I think you may have forgotten the rs.MoveNext() in a previous version of the code. Also, clean your target table, verify you're commiting (probably always) and don't ignore possible erros or exceptions.

What other information would help?
DoCmd is an Access command. I have tried with Execute too.
Whatever method I use, wether reading the recordset,  or doing the insert in the SQL statement, I get the same result.
What is baffling to me (and I've been progamming in COBOL, RPG (every version!) C++ and VBA for 30 years) is that the debug is correct, and I'm looking at the values after my insert. When in debug the rs! values show the correct value.

Thom,
It's a dummied down version of the SQL statement I have (it's 1900 characters long).
It's VBA - and if there is an issue with the code - please point it out, that's why I posted the question.
